# SD card becoming write protected on Nikon D5200

Tags: sdcard, error, nikon-d5200

I have a Nikon D5200, I am not able to delete photos on the SD card when it's connected to the computer. It shows, "The memory card is write protected."

I had searched on the net and found an article explaining how to remove write protection. I removed the write protection and then used the SD card with the camera. I tried connecting again to the system and it shows the same write protection issue.

Can anyone help me in this?

Answer (score 4):

Check the side of the SD card. There's a write protect switch that may have been moved to the 'lock' position.

Comment: To be more specific, it is usually silver/gray in color and very tiny. Test it by sticking it back into your SD reader and creating a .txt file in a directory to make sure you have the ability to write.

Comment: BobT & schnipdip thank you for your responds,
I had checked with the button, it's not locked. Even its in unlocked mode can't able to create a .txt file or remove any photo from it

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1:**

1. Start > Run > cmd
2. type "diskpart" -> runs diskpart.exe from system folder
3. type "list volume" -> now you see all your connected drives, see which one is the drive
4. type "select volume #" -> # being the letter of your drive
5. type "attributes disk clear readonly" -> removing the protection
6. Then open your SD, you can now edit, delete, move files.

**Solution 2:**

1. Plunge this drive or memory card to a computer. (Of course, you should use a card Reader to connect your memory card.)
2. Click “Start” on the taskbar to open “Run” and type in “regedit”.
3. Hit “HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE” to expand “System”.
4. Find “Current Control Set” in “System” list to click “Control”.
5. Check whether there is a key named “Storage Device Policies” to change the digit in the “DWORD value” box into "0" and press “OK”.
   But, if you cannot find the key named “Storage Device Policies”, you are supposed to create a one: right click “Control” to create a new key and name it as “Storage Device Policies”=> right click this new key to open “DWORD Value” and name it as “write protect”=> Double click it to change number.

Reference: [TomsHardware](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/296914-32-remove-write-protection-micro-card)

Comment: previously I had tried the first solution 

need to try the second one

Answer (score 1):

Have the same issue with my Panasonic lumix gx800. From a bit of googling, I understand this is normal behavior for cameras, presumably to avoid any loss of photos by human mistakes, data corruption, ransomware etc. Makes sense, I think, but would be nice to have an option in settings.

Answer (score 0):

In this context, it would also be helpful to note that SD cards and other flash memories switch to a readonly mode at the end of their life and then cannot be erased, written to, formatted or changed in any other way. Before that, the wear-leveling mechanism (implemented in the controller inside the card) ensures that individual "worn out" flash cells are marked as defective and cells from the card's spare cells area are used instead. At some point, however, the spare cells are used up and the card switches to readonly mode "to protect data loss". I have experienced this several times with SD cards and USB sticks. Unfortunately you can't find much info about this behavior, but I found this, for example:
https://superuser.com/questions/1300797/how-do-sd-cards-implement-their-end-of-life-write-protection
It gets annoying, if the camera, as in my case, does not report any error, although the photos haven't been saved...
Please let me know if there is another explanation and/or solution to this problem - what I have described merely reflects my experience, half-knowledge and guesses.

Answer (score 0):

Something you may want to check, on the back of your camera is a button with a key on or next to it... It's very easy to lock an image from the preview screen.